# I need a template function with a variable number of parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I need a template function with a variable number of parameters. Currently my problem is solved by using several template functions. But now I need to make a wrap method in my class function and other reasons to pack this code in one function.

```
static void sendData(SSL *ssl, Command com)
{
    std::string comStr(COM_SIZE, ' ');
    memcpy(&comStr[0], &com, COM_SIZE);
    sslWrite(ssl, comStr);
}

template<class T>
void sendData(SSL *ssl, Command com, const T &t)
{
    std::string serialArg;
    OByteStream obs(serialArg);
    obs << t;
    obs.flush();

    const int serialArgSize = serialArg.size();
    std::string comAndSerialData(COM_SIZE + serialArgSize, ' ');
    memcpy(&comAndSerialData[0], &com, COM_SIZE);
    memcpy(&comAndSerialData[COM_SIZE], &serialArg[0], serialArgSize);

    sslWrite(ssl, comAndSerialData);
}

template<class T1, class T2>
void sendData(SSL *ssl, Command com, const T1 &t1, const T2 &t2)
{
    std::string serialArgs;
    OByteStream obs(serialArgs);
    obs << t1 << t2;
    obs.flush();

    const int serialArgsSize = serialArgs.size();
    std::string comAndSerialData(COM_SIZE + serialArgsSize, ' ');
    memcpy(&comAndSerialData[0], &com, COM_SIZE);
    memcpy(&comAndSerialData[COM_SIZE], &serialArgs[0], serialArgsSize);

    sslWrite(ssl, comAndSerialData);
}

template<class T1, class T2, class T3>
void sendData(SSL *ssl, Command com, const T1 &t1, const T2 &t2, const T3 &t3)
{
    std::string serialArgs;
    OByteStream obs(serialArgs);
    obs << t1 << t2 << t3;
    obs.flush();

    const int serialArgsSize = serialArgs.size();
    std::string comAndSerialData(COM_SIZE + serialArgsSize, ' ');
    memcpy(&comAndSerialData[0], &com, COM_SIZE);
    memcpy(&comAndSerialData[COM_SIZE], &serialArgs[0], serialArgsSize);

    sslWrite(ssl, comAndSerialData);
}

//...
```

How can I write this in one function?

---

This is my attempt to use variadic templates

```
void flush(OByteStream &obs)
{
    obs.flush();
}

template<typename T, typename... Targs>
void flush(OByteStream &obs, T value, Targs... Fargs)
{
    obs << value;
    flush(obs, Fargs);
}

template<typename... Targs>
void sendData(SSL *ssl, Command com, Targs... Fargs)
{
    std::string serialArgs;
    OByteStream obs(serialArgs);
    flush(obs, Fargs);

    const int serialArgsSize = serialArgs.size();
    std::string comAndSerialData(COM_SIZE + serialArgsSize, ' ');
    memcpy(&comAndSerialData[0], &com, COM_SIZE);
    memcpy(&comAndSerialData[COM_SIZE], &serialArgs[0], serialArgsSize);

    sslWrite(ssl, comAndSerialData);
}
```

`flush(obs, Fargs);` - error C3520: 'Fargs' : parameter pack must be expanded in this context

Comment: Aren't [variadic template parameter packs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) of help for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inline void flush(OByteStream &obs)
{
    obs.flush();
}

template<typename T, typename... Targs>
void flush(OByteStream &obs, T &value, Targs&... Fargs)
{
    obs << value;
    flush(obs, Fargs...);
}

template<typename... Targs>
void sendData(SSL *ssl, Command com, Targs&... Fargs)
{
    std::string serialArgs;
    OByteStream obs(serialArgs);
    flush(obs, Fargs...);

    const int serialArgsSize = serialArgs.size();
    std::string comAndSerialData(COM_SIZE + serialArgsSize, ' ');
    memcpy(&comAndSerialData[0], &com, COM_SIZE);
    memcpy(&comAndSerialData[COM_SIZE], &serialArgs[0], serialArgsSize);

    sslWrite(ssl, comAndSerialData);
}
```

Comment: There is problem with rvalues: cannot convert argument 3 from 'bool' to 'bool &'

Comment: But if change Targs& to Targs&& and T& to T&& it works. Is it good solution?

Answer (score 6):

```
template<class...Ts>
void sendData(SSL *ssl, Command com, const Ts&... ts)
```

...
Replace the `<<` line with:

```
for_each_arg([&](auto&&t){obs << t;},ts...);
```

Write `for_each_arg`:

```
template<class F,class...Ts>
void for_each_arg(F&&f, Ts&&... ts){
  using discard=int[];
  (void)discard{ 0, ((
    f(std::forward<Ts>(ts))
  ),void(),0)...}
}
```

Which is arcane but efficient.

This gets harder on C++11, as you do not have `auto&&` lambdas.  You can write a hand-rolled struct with a template `operator()` instead.

This does not replace the zero arg case, naturally, and given how short your code is, I would not twist myself into pretzils to handle it.

---

How do you write a C++11 function object with a template operator() that replaces a C++14 auto lambda?

Suppose you have a C++14 lambda that looks like this:

```
auto f = [&](auto&& x) { /* some code */ };
```

to turn it into a C++11 function object with template `operator()`, first identify each actual thing you are capturing, and capture them manually.  Suppose `/* code */` used the names `bob` `alice` and implicitly used `this`.  Then rewrite the line like this:

```
auto f = [&bob, &alice, this](auto&& x) { /* some code */ };
```

where we list everything we capture.

Next, take `/* some code */` and make every use of `this` *explicit*.  If we used `m_x`, replace it with `this->m_x`.

The next step is to figure out the type of `bob` `alice` and `this`.  Suppose they are `Bob` `Alice` and `MyClass`.  Create a class that looks like:

```
struct function_object_f {
  Bob const& bob;
  Alice const& alice;
  MyClass* self;
};
```

with the captured variables in order.  Now add a `template operator()`:

```
struct function_object_f {
  Bob const& bob;
  Alice const& alice;
  MyClass* self;
  template<class X>
  void operator()(X&& x)const {
    /* some code */
  }
};
```

now, replace every explicit mention of `this` in `/* some code */` with `self`.

Put this class *before* your function you where using the lambda in.

Rewrite the original line:

```
auto f = function_object_f{bob, alice, this};
```

and we are done.  (note that the order of capture matters here: it must match the `function_object_f` member variable declarations).  `f` is nearly identical to a lambda, but its type has a name.

(For no-capture lambdas, it is missing implicit-cast-to-function pointer, but that is boilerplate for another day).

Comment: Doesn't this require the trailing arguments to be all the same type, whereas in the original code, the 1, 2 or 3 arguments can be all different types?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No : all of the types are forwarded through `Ts`, and into the lambda.

Comment: `void for_each_arg(F&&f, Ts&&ts) {` - error C3520: 'Ts' : parameter pack must be expanded in this context

Comment: @Ufx I fixed the typo.

Comment: `for_each_arg([&](auto&&t) {obs << t; }, ts...);` - error C3533: 'auto &&': a parameter cannot have a type that contains 'auto'

Comment: @Ufx As noted, that line is C++14.  To write it in C++11, you have to translate the lambda to a function object with a `template<class T> void operator()(T&& t)` that captures `obs` manually.

Comment: @Quentin could you add example for C++11 please?

Comment: I'll redirect that query to @Yakk ;)

Comment: @Ufx A brief lesson on writing a function object to replace a C++14 lambda has been added.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace both flush functions with

```
template<typename... Targs>
void flush(OByteStream &obs, Targs... Fargs)
{
    using swallow = int[sizeof...(Targs)];
    (void) swallow{(obs << Fargs, 0)...};
}
```

This technique avoids recursion. Of course, you can replace the `obs << Fargs` with whatever function call you need:

```
template<typename Callable, typename... Targs>
void call_for_each(Callable&& callable, Targs... Fargs)
{
    using swallow = int[sizeof...(Targs)];
    (void) swallow{(callable(Fargs), 0)...};
}
```